# Multi-page newsletter

Tags: html, dom, html-email, newsletter

I wonder if it is possible to create multi-paged e-newsletter. I know that the email clients are in general very restrictive (for a good reason of course) so one has to use plain table-based html for design and even images download has to be manually approved not to mention scripts. But maybe...with the help of html5 or other advanced technologies it could be possible to include the additional pages to the attachement and use them somehow. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best chances are creating "read more..." buttons that link to a webpage.

If you would want to have multipage newsletters, there are various options:

- <del>Frames</del>
- <del>Iframes</del>
- <del>Use of JavaScript</del>

Unfortunately, all of these options are sent straight to the spambox.

Even if there would be a HTML5 tag or element-only option, eg. a slider, most e-mail clients won't support these new features for the next billions of years. Webdev's complain about IE, but e-mail clients are much, much worse.

Comment: You're right, however, read more... button is fine only when you have internet access which causes no problems when you're in the city with desktop or laptop. However, when u use mobile technologies, the connection is much less stable and it would be nice if u could download the whole newsletter in one piece. I agree with you though that it probably won't be possible any time soon.

Comment: You can set up a bunch of minimal webpages for mobiles that require little bandwidth. Actually, it would most likely take **less** bandwidth because if you download all the content in one email, you download **all** content. If you use "read more..." links, the user can select what they are interested in and they will only have to download that. So the amount of data transferred depends on their needs.

Comment: Iframes and Javascript shouldn't be suggested/considered as options for html email.

Comment: @John You should kept on reading: "Unfortunately, all of these options are sent straight to the spambox."

Comment: @TimS. I did, but at first read thought it was misleading listing them out, even though you pointed out they were bad options. My apologies.

Comment: @John No, you are right. I've added additional markup to emphasize each being *bad* options.

Answer (score 1):

Generally email only supports (x)html and limited css. Unlike the ever-evolving web, popular email clients like Outlook for example, are out of date (and using the MS Word render engine). Much of html5/css3 that is common web practice today, is not widely supported across major email clients.

The only options you have as a link to more, is to host the additional information online (a landing page is typical), or to use anchor links and have the additional information further down in the email. Anchor links aren't 100% supported however. You may get iframes to work in one or two email clients but it will not work in most.

Javascript or any other server or client side language is NOT supported in email.